# YUI Anim on After event?

Tags: javascript, yui, yui2

There is a way to trigger an event after an animation is done?
what's the cose for it?
I'm very new with YUI libraries and i'm getting lost..

my cose now is

```
    var anim = new Y.Anim({
        node: node,
        duration: 1.0,
        easing: Y.Easing.easeOut
    });
```

...etc

Note: This applies to YUI2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup!  Something like:

```
var myAnim = new YAHOO.util.Anim("yourId", {
   left: {from: 0, to:75}
}, 1);

myAnim.onComplete.subscribe(function() {
   alert('Done!');
});
```

See http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/animation/index.html for more examples.

Comment: is this YUI 2 or 3? it doesnt sound to work on my code...i think im using yui3

Comment: This is for 2.x.  I've never used 3.x, but the docs have some information here: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/anim/end-event.html

Answer (score 1):

To do something after an animation is done, you just need to listen to the "end" event:

```
var anim = new Y.Anim({
    node: node,
    duration: 1.0,
    easing: Y.Easing.easeOut,
    on: {
        end: function (e) {
            // your stuff here
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is, that since an animation takes time, you might want to be notified when the animation completes to perform any additional logic you might need: Here are a few uses for that event:

1. Trigger additional animations once an animation completes. This can be on the same element or a completely different part of the UI.
2. Remove the element from the DOM. Perhaps it was a popup-window, that once it is closed (with an animation), is no longer needed in the DOM
3. Something other, like filling the element with content etc.